# use dynamic Text in contains function

Tags: full-text-search

I have a query to find something in a long text by a dynamic parameter
this is my query:

```
declare @searchTerm nvarchar(100)
set @searchTerm='Product/IndexShowProduct/'
select 
REPLACE(product.name, ' ', '-') as lnkName,
product.*,ProductCategory.Name as ProductCategory,Shop.Name as shopname
,isnull(Picture.PicturePath,'DefaultProduct.jpg') as PicturePath
 from Product
 left join ProductCategory  on ProductCategory.ID =Product.ID_ProductCategory 
 left join Picture on Product.ID_pic=Picture.ID 
 left join Shop on shop.id=product.ID_Shop
 LEFT JOIN
  (select P.ID as POrdered from Product P , Article A 
 where  A.ID=@IDArticle 
 and **A.SiteContent like '%'+ltrim(rtrim(@searchTerm))+ltrim(rtrim(str(P.id)))+'%')**
  P
 ON P.POrdered=Product.ID
 
 where Product.ID_ProductCategory=case when @ID_ProductCategory=0 then ID_ProductCategory else @ID_ProductCategory end
order by P.POrdered desc
```

you know this part has low performance so I would like to use fulltextsearch in this part like this phrase:

contains(A.SiteContent,ltrim(rtrim(@searchTerm))+ltrim(rtrim(str(P.id))))

but it sounds that the function "contains" doesn't like dynamic parameter "p.id"!!!! I can't use the static text for search.is there any problem with that?

I look forward to hearing from you.

best regards.